# Pandas: How do I see the overlap between two lists in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, overlap

I have a dataframe with two columns that each contain lists.  I want to determine the overlap between the lists in the two columns.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one':[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h', 'i', 'j']], 
                   'two':[['b', 'c', 'd'], ['f', 'g', 'h',], ['l', 'm', 'n']]})
```

```
        one         two
    0   [a, b, c]   [b, c, d]
    1   [d, e, f]   [f, g, h]
    2   [h, i, j]   [l, m, n]
```

Ultimately, I want it to look like:

```
        one         two             overlap
    0   [a, b, c]   [b, c, d]       [b, c]
    1   [d, e, f]   [f, g, h]       [f]
    2   [h, i, j]   [l, m, n]       []
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no efficient vectorial way to perform this, the fastest approach will be a list comprehension with `set` intersection:

```
df['overlap'] = [list(set(a)&set(b)) for a,b in zip(df['one'], df['two'])]
```

Output:

```
         one        two overlap
0  [a, b, c]  [b, c, d]  [b, c]
1  [d, e, f]  [f, g, h]     [f]
2  [h, i, j]  [l, m, n]      []
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using `pandas`

The `Pandas` way of doing this could be like this -

```
f = lambda row: list(set(row['one']).intersection(row['two']))
df['overlap'] = df.apply(f,1)
print(df)
```

```
         one        two overlap
0  [a, b, c]  [b, c, d]  [b, c]
1  [d, e, f]  [f, g, h]     [f]
2  [h, i, j]  [l, m, n]      []
```

The apply function goes row by row (axis=1) and finds the `set.intersection()` between the list in column `one` and column `two`. Then it returns the result as a list.

> `Apply` methods are not the fastest, but quite readible imo. But since your question doesn't mention speed as a criteria, this wont be an issue.

Additionally, you could use either of the two expressions as your lambda function, as both do the same task -

```
#Option 1:
f = lambda x: list(set(x['one']) & set(x['two']))

#Option 2:
f = lambda x: list(set(x['one']).intersection(x['two']))
```

## Using `Numpy`

You can use the numpy method `np.intersect1d` as well along with a map over the 2 series.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['overlap'] = pd.Series(map(np.intersect1d, df['one'], df['two']))
print(df)
```

```
         one        two overlap
0  [a, b, c]  [b, c, d]  [b, c]
1  [d, e, f]  [f, g, h]     [f]
2  [h, i, j]  [l, m, n]      []
```

---

## Benchmarks

Adding some benchmarks for reference -

```
%timeit [list(set(a)&set(b)) for a,b in zip(df['one'], df['two'])]        #list comprehension
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['one']).intersection(x['two'])),1)  #apply 1
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['one']) & set(x['two'])),1)         #apply 2
%timeit pd.Series(map(np.intersect1d, df['one'], df['two']))              #numpy intersect1d
```

```
6.99 µs ± 17.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
167 µs ± 830 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
166 µs ± 338 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
84.1 µs ± 270 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `applymap` to convert your lists to sets and using `set.intersection` to find the overlap:

```
df.join(df.applymap(set).apply(lambda x: set.intersection(*x),axis=1).map(list).rename('overlap'))
```